# How to group by a single item without including it in the GROUP BY clause?

Tags: sql-server

My desire is to have a sales report grouped by product description that shows the quantity of each item  and the price. The problem I am running into is that I only want to group by the product description and not other fields that I have to include because there are aggregate functions in the SELECT clause. I have googled and searched everywhere and have not found a simple solution.

Comment: paste your query here... with table structure, sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't using a single SELECT, but, you could use a subquery to calculate aggregated vales.

Given two tables, Products and Sales:

Products

```
ProductID
Description1
Description2
MoreProductAttributes
```

Sales

```
ProductID,
Date,
Quantity,
Amount
```

You can define a query similar to this:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.Description1, p.Description2. p.MoreAttributes,
       s.TotalQty, s.TotalAmount
FROM Products p
     INNER JOIN (SELECT ProductID, SUM(Quantity) TotalQty, SUM(Import) TotalAmount
                 FROM Sales
                 WHERE Date BETWEEN Date1 AND Date2
                 GROUP BY ProductId) s
     ON o.ProducID = s.ProductID;
```